# cant access element using selenium, returns an empty list with no error message

Tags: python, selenium

I'm practicing selenium and trying to acquire data in a div class from bet365. I don't get an error message through finding it with an XPath but the value is always returned as an empty list.
I have tried different elements on the web page but with no success. The method used works on pinnacle but not bet365.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


class Bet365:
    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": 
    """Object.defineProperty(navigator, 
    'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})"""})

    url = 'https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B12/C20426855/D48/E36/F36/'
    xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    matchesTable = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
    print(matchesTable)
    
    


    time.sleep(20)



    
Bet365()
```

I'd like for the program to print some sort of recognition that it has accessed the element then to finally print all the values inside to text

Comment: What are all the data do you want to extract?

Comment: what does the command `driver.execute_cdp_cmd(...)` do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong xpath, use the following

```
xpath = '//div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div'
matchesTable = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

Alternatively you can use a css selector and the class name of the table

```
css = 'div.gl-MarketGroupContainer'
matchesTable = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)
```